# What is wrong with my SQL syntax for an UPDATE with a JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, sql-update, inner-join

I have two tables, related by a common key. So TableA has key AID and value Name and TableB has keys AID, BID and values Name, Value:

```
AID Name
74  Alpha

AID BID Name  Value
74  4   Beta  Brilliance
```

I would like to update the TableB Value here from Brilliance to Barmy, using just the Name fields. I thought I could do it via an UPDATE containing a JOIN, but Access (I know...) is complaining with 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ' and then everything from 'Barmy' here:

```
UPDATE tB
SET tB.Value='Barmy'
FROM `TableB` tB
INNER JOIN `TableA` tA
  ON tB.AID=tA.AID
WHERE tB.Name='Beta'
  AND tA.Name='Alpha';
```

What is my heinous crime? Or is it just Access not conforming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oddly, I've discovered the answer is to use an implicit JOIN:

```
UPDATE `TableA`, `TableB` 
 SET `TableB`.Value = 'Barmy'
WHERE `TableA`.AID=`TableB`.AID
 AND `TableA`.Name='Alpha'
 AND `TableB`.Name='Beta';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to be honest i haven't touched ACCESS in years (luckily) [this thread](http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-360363.html) seems to suggest this is the correct syntax.

```
UPDATE TableB tB
SET tB.BValue='Barmy'
INNER JOIN TableA tA
  ON tB.AID=tA.AID
WHERE tB.Name='Beta'
  AND tA.Name='Alpha';
```

Comment: +1. Access doesn't do `UPDATE...FROM` like SQL Server, but it does support `JOIN`s in the update (this, honestly, makes more sense anyway, IMO)

Answer (score 1):

I reckon, based on a test:

```
UPDATE TableB tB
INNER JOIN TableA tA
  ON tB.AID=tA.AID
SET tB.Value='Barmy'
WHERE tB.Name='Beta'
  AND tA.Name='Alpha';
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write in Hoyle ANSI (which does not recognize the FROM clause in an UPDATE statement):

```
UPDATE TableB
SET BValue="Barmy"
Where Name="Beta"
    And Exists( Select 1 
                From TableA As TA 
                Where TA.Name = "Alpha"
                    And TA.AID = TableB.AID );
```

One last addition, Access deals with JOINS in an UPDATE statement by putting them in the UPDATE clause like so:

```
UPDATE TableB
    INNER JOIN TableA tA
        ON TableB.AID=tA.AID    
SET TableB.BValue="Barmy"
WHERE TableB.Name="Beta"
  AND tA.Name="Alpha";
```

**EDIT** One other item, Access uses double quotes to identify strings, not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response Thomas, but I've just tried replacing all the aliases with the original table names in backticks, and I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Access does not support `UPDATE...FROM`, but you can join in the statement. See Martijn's answer.

Comment: Jet/ACE SQL doesn't support backticks, either. They have no meaning to Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 0):

it may not know what tB is until you get to the aliasing in the `FROM` line.   Try `UPDATE TableB ....`

Comment: I've tried replacing all the aliases with the table name in backticks, and still no dice.

Comment: As said in other comments, Access does not support `UPDATE...FROM`, but you can join in the statement. See Martijn's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does Access do subqueries?

```
UPDATE TableB
SET TableB.Value='Barmy'
WHERE TableB.AID = (SELECT TableA.AID WHERE TableA.Name='Alpha')
```

Comment: Access does support subqueries, but it should not be necessary in this case.